# Multithreaded galib247 genetic algorithm stuck in local maxima

Tags: c++, multithreading, genetic-algorithm

I added multithreading support to galib247 (below), but I'm still seeing problems whereby solutions were getting stuck in local maxima.

Perhaps it's a shortcoming of genetic algorithms in general.  Let me know if anyone has any suggestions. I've tried running 1000 independent populations, that are prioritized based on how recently the population has found a better solution, but I still think it's not finding the best solution.

I've also tried modifying the mutator. Perhaps the solution set it too complicated, there are a lot of local maxima. It usually finds different local maxima in every one of the 1000 pools of pools, but occasionally one of the pools of pools finds a better answer and is prioritized for scheduling.

What I'm trying to do is generate an optimal technical analysis indicator list with parameters to an FX trade signal generator for live trading based on an expanding set of historical prices. There was a book about it years ago, I think the author's name was Katz.

I'm testing the variance of the results against a second historical price set but basically, the real test is whether or not it is predictive of future prices.

GAPopulation.C (http://lancet.mit.edu/ga/Copyright.html):

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/threadpool.hpp>

boost::threadpool::pool GAPopulation::thpool(5);

void GAPopulationEvaluatorWorker(void* individual_ptr) {
    ((GAGenome*) individual_ptr)->evaluate();
    boost::this_thread::yield();
}

void GAPopulation::DefaultEvaluator(GAPopulation& p) {
    for(int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++) {
        thpool.schedule(boost::bind(GAPopulationEvaluatorWorker, p.individual_ptr(i)));
    }

    thpool.wait();
}
```

Comment: It's been a couple of years since I've been using genetic algorithms, but probably your mutators are not "good enough" to overcome a local maximum.

Comment: But I can also imagine that multiple threads could cause problems, because results are not shared between threads. I'm not sure how genetic algorithms can be parallelized.

Comment: @Simon.  the mutator, yeah.  I think that's the problem but I don't know what to do.  Each evalution only takes about 50 milliseconds and I was using a population size of 100 or 500.  What I observed is that it divides the execution time of a single generation of the population by the number of CPU's.  There is some overhead for each generation because that part is single-threaded but CPU is basically pegged at 100% on a multi-cpu system

Comment: so yeah, it's already parellelized, but a "good enough" DEFAULT_REAL_MUTATOR (or DEFAULT_REAL_CROSSOVER) is the probably the exact problem.  not sure what to do

Comment: It really is crucial to have a mutator, which is diverse enough. I don't remember exactly how galib worked, but maybe you can have multiple mutators, which change different aspects of your problem.

Comment: hmm, like one mutator to change the number of indicators, one to change the parameters, and so forth. thanks, I'll try that

Comment: I think it's more of a mathematical problem, so maybe you get better answers on a different SE site (mathematics or statistics).

Comment: Are you parallelizing each new simulation of each new mutated-models and then rejoining the threads and averaging the best N models correct?

Comment: @JosephFranciscus let's say that the population has 125 members and a 20% retention rate.  each generation 100 new members have to be created from the retained 25 using mutators and what-not and evaluated.  This is what I am doing in 5 threads, so each thread handles about 20 calculations.  after all 100 new members are added to compose the new 125 member generation, a **single thread** determines the best 25 for the next generation, but that takes very little time because the **evaluator is parallelized**.  it populates the thread pool with 100 tasks every generation

Comment: this is in addition to the 1000 "pools of pools" that I tried.  Only one pool gets evaluated at a time (using parallelization) but if it recently improved (not stuck) it is scheduled more often

Comment: I'm sorry to use bold, but I think that I make no sense otherwise.  it's only a single line of code hehe

Comment: Have you verified your solution works in a single-threaded context?

Comment: `evaluator is parallelized` This seems suspicious to me. Genetic algorithms tend to perform poorly on multi-core systems because they inevitably have to be rejoined by some single thread to determine the best (as you inevitably have to compare each one to determine the "best"). Are you sure the threads in the `evaluator` are rejoined before comparison?

Comment: @JosephFranciscus absolutely certain.  the evaluator is extremely complex, and it produces a float "score" and takes time.  sorting the the floats in the single thread takes no time at all.  I think you are wrong.  no problem though, I don't think I'm being clear enough.  the paralellization code simply works, the problem is the local maxima

Comment: ` a single thread determines the best 25 for the next generation` you said so yourself what was I wrong about? (I'm sure your program is relatively fast, I'm comparing it to let's say a NeuralNetwork where you can parallelize as many examples in a batch as you want).

Comment: @JosephFranciscus so I think that what you said that parallelization is a problem with GA what wrong, no worries, it's not a crime and your other content is extremely useful after the preprocessor deleted that assertion... yeah I'll try a neural network next

Comment: @JosephFranciscus what do mean by **works single-threaded context**.. do you mean is it profitable?? well, yes, but the problem is that the commission are too high and I'm trying to find better trade signals to overcome the FX trade commissions.. it's better than waking up periodically and trading in random directions, which I've also tried.. that makes money too though if you can get the commission down with an institutional connection

Comment: @JosephFranciscus and the single line of code invoking boost::thread_pool makes galib247 4 times faster, so yeah... the multi-thread improvements have already been observed... I'l probably use a neural network instead, pretty much knew that..  if you have time and want a SVN connection to I can give you one if you want to cur/paste a neural network wrapper you can use the trader once it's done.. assuming it makes money.. I could also pay you if you can do it in a few hours

Answer (score 2):

Do you think your problem is caused by the multi-threading? I wouldn't think so...

GA's always have the problem of overcoming local maxima. I was taught that as program time goes on, you're supposed to decrease the mutation rate to keep from jumping down. But recently, I made a GA that increased its mutation rate based on the lack of genetic diversity in its population. (Had to come up with a function that could calculate diversity).

With GA's, there are many things you need to do well: #1, have a solid way of calculating fitness that can be performed very quickly. This simply can't be done with a lot of problems. #2, describe your problem in a set of genes. Again, that can be really hard to do. #3, who to breed and how to breed them. I'd rather have a diverse breeding pool where the mid-performing genes can last for several generations, especially if your problem is overcoming local maxima. And of course, #4, your strategy for mutation. It just may not be enough to flip 1 bit on a .1% chance. Or it might be too much. How do you breed or mutate things like floating-point numbers? Flipping 1 bit a) makes a drastic change and b) has no discernible impact on fitness (it could be good or bad depending on the other bits).

So using a GA requires a lot of tuning. Evaluate #1 and #2 and make sure you're happy with it. Experiment with breeding. "Killing your parents" might help. Maybe keep a few of the parents around, but breed everyone but the lowest 25%. That way there's less of a chance of jumping down, but a good gene has a chance to go through a few sub-par mutations that might in the end create a better gene.

I hear you can use a GA to set the initial weights for a neural net. I've always wanted to try that, but I still haven't gotten around to writing neural nets.

Comment: no, multithreading is just a quick optimization that makes it about 399% faster on a 4 core system.. I think you are right. basically, I am using integers as genes, here a=1 specifieds a moving average crossover, b=9 specifies a 9 period fast moving average, c=26 specifies a 26 period slow moving average.. a=2 would specify a trailing stop loss, b=50 would indicate a 50 pip trigger, c=10 would indicate a 10 pip stop.. it's a bit more complicated than that, but it takes about 50 milliseconds to loop through a few years of price history in the evaluator

Comment: I'll read your suggestions from the mutator again, I think it's using a gausian distribution to mutate the integer parameters.. there are like 10 or 20 technical analysis indicators so the number of combinations is astronomical.. I think the number of combinations is too large or it's simply impossible to predict future FX prices

Comment: In evolutionary algorithms in general, the lack of genetic diversity in a population is a problem referred to as niching.  This problem is known and addressed since the inception of EAs in particular, and heuristic algorithms in general.  The Evolution Strategies' variant of evolutionary algorithms even includes a strategy parameter that determines the variance of the probability distribution used in its mutation operator to avoid niching.